# How I do get the location value from GPS and GPRS?

Tags: android, gps, location, gprs

I'm try to get latitude and longitude values via the `android.Location` class, but sometimes my system can't get the correct value; it is lat: 0.00 and lng: 0.00. Perhaps it returns an incorrect value because Android detects GPS only.

Now, I know that location value can detect by GPRS/WiFi, and how do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. Here are docs and examples:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html